# Having trouble plotting the solutions of an equation that has many roots

Tags: plotting, complex

Below is my current code. I have tried to plot Points 2 in the complex plane using suggestions from prior questions, but am still having some difficulties achieving a plot (Also, if there is a cleaner way to do any of the following steps, I am open to suggestions). My current plots are blank.

```
MA = 2
MB = 5 
ma = MA/(MA + MB)
mb = MB/(MB + MA)
a = 5
phivals = Table[i, {i, 0, 2 π, π/100.}];
Points1 = {};
Do[Points1 = 
Append[Points1, {phivals[[i]], 
NSolve[{ma/(z - a)^2 + mb/(z + a)^2 == 
Exp[I  φ] /. {φ -> phivals[[i]]}}, 
z]}], {i, Length[phivals]}]
Points2 = Catenate[Thread /@ (Points1 /. r == v_ :> v /. Or -> List)]
```

This is one of my attempts to plot the points...

```
ListPolarPlot[{Re[Points2], Im[Points2]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

This is my second attempt to plot the points...

```
p = ListPolarPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ Points2, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
PlotRange -> All, ImagePadding -> 40, AspectRatio -> 1, 
Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{Im, None}, {Re, "complex plane"}}, 
PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[.02]]]; Show[p]
```

Here are *a couple* of the points...

```
{{0., {z -> -5.84618}}, {0., {z -> 5.53625}}, {0., {z -> 
4.46333}}, {0., {z -> -4.1534}}, {0.0628319, {z -> -5.84576 + 
0.0266388 I}}, {0.0628319, {z -> 
5.53598 - 0.0169473 I}}, {0.0628319, {z -> 4.46361 + 0.0170001 I}}
```

Answer (score 5):

Does this do what you want?

```
Points2 = Catenate[Thread[{#, z /. #2}] & @@@ Points1];

ListPolarPlot[{Re[Points2], Im[Points2]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Or maybe:

```
ListPolarPlot[ReIm @ Points2, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

---

By the way you should avoid [`Do`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html) with [`Append`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Append.html) in most cases, and use [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) instead.  You can also iterate over a list directly.  You can write:

```
Points2 =
  Table[Thread @ {φ, 
      z /. NSolve[{ma/(z - a)^2 + mb/(z + a)^2 == Exp[I φ]}, 
        z]}, {φ, phivals}] // Catenate;
```

Comment: Getting closer, thanks for your help. I goofed and realized I am only to plot the z values.

Answer (score 3):

A quick fix:

```
ListPolarPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ (Flatten@Points1 /. Rule[_, c_] -> c),
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
 PlotRange -> All,
 ImagePadding -> 40,
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {{Im, None}, {Re, "complex plane"}},
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[.02]]]
```

[image]

A better and faster solution (like Mr. Wizard already noted) would be to use `Table`. Also, you don't need to precompute `phivals`:

```
fun = ma/(z - a)^2 + mb/(z + a)^2 == Exp[I \[CurlyPhi]];

tab = Flatten@Table[z /. NSolve[fun, z], {\[CurlyPhi], 0, 2 Pi, Pi/100.}]
```

and then

```
 ListPolarPlot[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ tab ...]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!